# Returning array instead of proxy in vue js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

im new to vuejs and ive been struggling with trying to use the array of companies that has been assigned the `response.data` eventhough it has been used normally before.

```
export default{
    name:"companies-list",
    data(){
        return{
            companies: [],
            currentCompany: null,
            currentIndex: -1,
            id:"",
            search:'',
            isEmpty:'true',
            rows: []
            
        };
    },


         retrieveCompanies(){
            CompanyService.getAllCompanies()
            .then(response =>{
                this.companies = response.data;
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(e=> {
                console.log(e);
            });
        },
```

```
 mounted(){
        this.retrieveCompanies();
        console.log(this.companies);
    }
```

Here the `console.log(this.companies)` returns a proxy with an **empty array**. I'm trying to assign the contents of the companies that contain the companies from the `retrieveCompanies()` method to the empty `rows[]` array so that i can perform a filter on the rows according to the properties of the companies such as id and name. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `CompanyService.getAllCompanies()`  is asynchronous ... so `console.log(this.companies);` happens BEFORE `this.companies = response.data;`

Comment: if you `return CompanyService.getAllCompanies()` ... then in mounted `this.retrieveCompanies().then(() => console.log(this.companies))` will produce the expected result

Comment: Stop console logging everything and you won't be confused about what you see. Log when you have to and typically only when you've exhausted every other debugging method, not before

Comment: Oh okay understood. Where should i return CompanyService.getAllCompanies()?

Comment: @Phil Yeah i figured that its very confusing. I'm still new to javascript as well so i didn't really know how to debug.

Comment: If you want to assign the response data to `rows`, why are you assigning it to `companies`

Comment: The [Vue DevTools browser extension](https://devtools.vuejs.org/) is invaluable

Comment: Im trying to filter the companies that i have so i created an empty array called rows to show the rows that have been filtered other than showing the whole list of companies

Comment: Use [computed properties](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) for providing filtered or transformed views of raw data